# Local Cocoa Pod in existing Project iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am following the below steps:-

1) Created a Project , Single View Application from Xcode

2) `pod init`

3) `pod spec create ProjectPod`

ProjectPod has ,   `s.source_files  = "Pods/Classes/**/*"`

4) `pod spec lint`
 fails , as source url is invalid URL s.source       = { :git => "URL", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

5) `pod install`

This creates a 'Development Pods' into the following location. The ideal structure is listed below:-
1) Development Pods -> Red ->Classes
2) Development Pods -> Red -> Supporting Files

But  I get the following structure. I don't know where could be the issue.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want? Create a new pod, with example app?

Comment: I have a existing project. So I want to add Developments Pods as well as use the pods available on the Coocapods website. Later on if I want to add a second project, I should be able to do it in the same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If do you already have a valid pod with valid `podspec`, you can refer to local pod with

```
pod 'RedPod', :path => 'my/path/to/podspec'
```

[You can seen a example where.](https://github.com/brunomacabeusbr/TvLightSegments) In this example, I have a pod with example app, both use a same `Podfile` and same workspace.

And, if the pod can install, but, has no file, check `source_files` parameter in `podspec`.

Comment: But , what would you specify in th git url for that local pod

Comment: I think that you don't need specify a `source` if you only use as a local pod.